# Rails ApplicationHelper Escaping HTML without return statement

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, helper, actionview, escaping

When I write

```
module ApplicationHelper   
  def flash_helper 
    flash.each do |key, msg|
      content_tag :div, msg, :class => key
      ## "<div class=\"key\">" + msg + "</div>"
    end
  end
end
```

I do not get anything unless I `return` the statement. The HTML is escaped in my view when I call `<%= flash_helper %>`. What gives? How can I prevent the HTML from being escaped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `concat` method (Rails >= 2.2.1)

```
module ApplicationHelper   
  def flash_helper 
    flash.each do |key, msg|
      concat(content_tag :div, msg, :class => key)
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

can you re-write it like this?

```
module ApplicationHelper   
  def flash_helper 
    s = ""
    flash.each do |key, msg|
      s += content_tag :div, msg, :class => key
      ## "<div class=\"key\">" + msg + "</div>"
    end
    return s
  end
end
```

Comment: I was writing it like that and had the same problem as the OP.